# SQL: Concatenate colums in different lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

SQL: How can I concatenate below columns(a,b,c) as separate lines and if any field is blank then don't add blank line? All the 3 columns have below datatype and sample data.

a (date)
b (int)
c (varchar)

**Sample data**

```
 a           b    c
2016-03-17  123  John
2018-05-21       Smith
2023-06-05  451  Park
```

**Expected Result:**

```
2016-03-17  
123 
John

2018-05-21
Smith

2023-06-05  
451 
Park
```

I tried CHAR(13) but it doesn't work in SQL SSMS (19.0.1).

Comment: What are you using as your front end?  Typically this kind of formating is done in the displaying application, not in data retrieval layer

Comment: Also if it is being displayed in HTML you can add in `<BR/>` to go to the next line.

Comment: Front end is Microsoft AX dynamics. I am using SQL server 2022 in Azure and trying to write the query in SSMS (19.0.1). Result will be stored back in SQL table before pushing the result in to AX. I need to achieve this through SQL query.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use unpivot

```
;with _list(a,b,c) as (
    select  
    cast( a as varchar(100)) a, 
    cast( b as varchar(100)) b,
    cast( c as varchar(100)) c
    from  TestB
    where a is not null or b  is not null or c  is not null
)
select value
from _list
unpivot(value for col in (a, b, c) )un
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9M2f7ReD)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate with separator maybe?

```
 SELECT CONCAT_WS (CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),a,b,c)[EXPECTED RESULT]FROM TABLE
```